# Dominated convergence with variable limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Given two functions, $f, g \in C_c^{\infty}[-1,1]$ is the set of smooth functions that are compactly supported on $[-1,1]$, I want to evaluate:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n f(x/n)g(x) \text{d}x.
$$

If we let $h_n(x) = f(x/n)g(x)$, then $h_n(x) \to f(0) g(x)$ pointwise, can I find a dominating function and use the dominated convergence theorem here? I'm a bit confused since the limits of integration are variable, but since the support of both functions is on the interval $[-1,1]$ can I just ignore this?

Comment: Looks like a typo in the question somewhere, $g$ needs to be defined outside the interval $[-1,1]$ for the integral to make sense.  Of course, I don't really know what $C_c^{\infty}[-1,1]$ means (what is that $c$ subscript?)

Comment: @Michael I've clarified in the question

Comment: I don't think anyone would write a problem like that and assume we know that $g$ is supposed to be zero outside.

Comment: @Michael Sorry I thought the $c$ subscript notation was standard

Comment: Standard for what?

Comment: @Michael to indicate that the functions are compactly supported on the interval, as I clarified in the question

Comment: Too much loaded notation for me to help here.  I don't know what "compactly supported" is supposd to mean. I observe that if $f$ is continuous on a compact interval then it is bounded and that would perhaps lead to a natural bound for dominated convergence (assuming you are really integrating over $\int_{-1}^1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hypothesis that $\text{supp}(g)\subseteq[-1,1]$, then for all $n \geq 1$
$$
\int_{-n}^n f(x/n)g(x) dx = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x/n)g(x) dx,
$$
and the answer is somewhat trivial.
For a matter of commodity, suppose that $f(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, we can define $m = \min_{x\in[-1,1]}\{f(x)\}$ and $M = \max_{x\in[-1,1]}\{f(x)\}$. Then for all $n>1$
$$
m\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) dx\leq \int_{-1}^{1} f(x/n)g(x) dx \leq M\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) dx.
$$
A similar answer applies if $\text{supp}(g)\subseteq[-k,k]$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Some trouble arises if $\text{supp}(g)$ is not compact.
For instance, let $g(x)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x)$ be your favorite smooth function such that

- $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$;
- $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|\leq1/2$ and
- $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|\geq0$.

Then
$$
\int_{-n}^n f(x/n)g(x) dx \geq \int_{-n/2}^{n/2} f(x/n)g(x) dx = \int_{-n/2}^{n/2} 1 \cdot 1 dx = n.
$$
As a consequence, the sequence $n \mapsto \int_{-n}^{n} f(x/n)g(x) dx$ diverges.

Comment: Your second line of inequalities need fixing if $g$ is allowed to be negative. Though, I think the spirit of this answer is similar to my above comment that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks, I added the hypotheses that $f, g \geq 0$.

Comment: Looks good (+1).